# Wordpress home page doesn't work, but other pages do. How to rectify?

Tags: errors, homepage

http://blog.sanspace.in/

My blog home page is messed up. None of the plugins or sidebar widgets are working. Only the latest post is showed that too partially.

However, other pages and posts (accessing through their URL) seems fine.

http://blog.sanspace.in/contact/ [page]
http://blog.sanspace.in/hello-world/ [post]

I am not sure what exactly the problem is. Could anyone help me with this? Is there anything wrong with the wordpress settings? Else, something needs to be done with my server settings?

**update**: I have hosted it with hostso in a shared hosting plan. I did not modify any WP files. My home page is a default WP home which shows the latest post.

**update** _*closed*_ : The problem was with the json_last_error() method I used in the latest post. Somehow the method is no longer supported by my server it seems. It caused all the problems.

Comment: is your home page set to static page or posts page?
did you modify the template?
what kind of server is behind your page?

please be a bit more specific, when asking a question.

Comment: Try updating your theme. I just did it and it worked. Maybe your plugin version you updated is higher than your theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the page is truncated due to a fatal error.

Look for an error log file in the wp directory or add the following line to wp-config.php to hopefully see the error text:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I am near to the solution. There was some problem with Exec-PHP plugin. I deactivated that. Still, some plugins (syntax highlighter) doesn't work at the homepage as they do when accessing via another URL.

Comment: Silly me. I didn't even thought of trying debugging. :-(